# How to ssh within iPython notebook?

Tags: python, bash, ssh, jupyter-notebook

I'm attempting to SSH within an ipython notebook as follows:

```
%%bash

ssh myserver.something.com
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

How can I SSH within an iPython notebook?

Comment: try `ssh -t` to force a pseudo-tty. You may need `ssh -tt`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh -t` or `ssh -tt` in order to force pseudo-tty allocation even if stdin is not a terminal.

Comment: Are you sure that this makes sense in a notebook cell? The cell is basically executing a script and does not work like an interactive shell.

Comment: In that case, redirect stdin from /dev/null

Comment: Looks like neither ssh -t nor ssh -tt work. How would one go about redirecting stdin from /dev/null?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you are asking how to run a terminal from within a cell that can show the feedback from the commands given.

If this is what you are looking for then first go to your main tree at `http://localhost:8888/tree` and open a new terminal by clicking the new button on the right side of the screen and then Terminal. This will open a terminal at `http://localhost:8888/terminals/1`

[image: Start New Terminal]

While this will probably be enough for most people, if you want your terminal to be in-line you can use **`IFrame`** to show your Terminal within a cell by directing it to `http://localhost:8888/terminals/1` where your terminal is located.

```py
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame("http://localhost:8888/terminals/1", 900, 500)
```

or

```html
%%html
<iframe src="http://localhost:8888/terminals/1", width=900, height=500></iframe>
```

You will now have an active in-line terminal that you can use to ssh or run any other commands

[image: Showing The Terminal Working In Cell Output]